# How do I fix an importing error with anaconda on PyCharm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ide, pycharm, anaconda

I am on Windows 10, I've been using matplotlib as part of anaconda with PyCharm as my IDE for a while but today when I opened it and ran my script it gives me:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

the full error message is:

```
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Myproject/Myprogram", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 36, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _image
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_image.py", line 7, in <module>
    __bootstrap__()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_image.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
    imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I added every PATH variables I could think of but it is still giving me the same error. I uninstalled/reinstalled both anaconda and Pycharm to no avail.

As I said this is very odd because the exact same script had been running without problems for a while.

Comment: I've got two students in my class this semester who have just begun having this problem. I fear there will soon be more. We are using Jupyter notebook. The issue is around loading matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my students reported the same issue with import matplotlib into Jupyter notebook. He removed Anaconda with the software add/remove tool, removed the Anaconda folder, and then reinstalled. That seems to have fixed things for him. This has now worked in two cases.

Comment: Doh! My student is running Windows 8.1. Perhaps that is the difference?

Comment: Neither of them has changed anything. I'm thinking Windows update might be involved. Can you check for updates? I'm eager to find what is going on before it happens to more of my students.

Comment: One more thing. He reports that he removed with the add/remove tool, and DELETED the Anaconda folder before reinstalling. Perhaps that is the difference?

Comment: That did the trick!!!!!! Thank you so much for your help I was starting to loose hope... so it appears that deleting the Anaconda3 folder before reinstalling fixes the problem for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I could **create** import errors by using PyCharm's module update function. Instead, on Windows, go to the command line, and use the 
`conda update <module name>` command.  This will fetch the modules from the right repositories.
Running `conda update anaconda` fixed my import problems by downgrading many packages I had updated with PyCharm's update facility.